# Understanding USB3.0 over-current detection circuit

Tags: current, usb, current-limiting, over-current

I'm trying to understand how the following over-current protection circuit works:

[image]

[image]
the way I understand this, as long as +VBUS_USB3_P0 = 5V and it's equal to +5V_ALW, there is no current current going through F2. but In over current situation, +VBUS_USB3_P0 can go below 5V (and higher current), where a current must go through F2, and that will drag Cathode voltage of D88 low, and that will drag USB_OCP_ALL# down and send an indication to CPU/Controller.

Is my analysis right?

Comment: Do you mean "detection" instead of "protection"? Unless there's something else important about `+5V_ALW`, it seems the fuse provides OCP. Note that the output might not be fully shorted out, so an analog input, or a threshold close to 5V, should be used to detect partial drop.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, Yes I meant detection. But how does the circuit work? how is USB_OCP_ALL# is eventually pulled low?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, it will be pulled low as the output voltage drops (presumably because the fuse has opened).